# Django ManyToMany filter()

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model:

```
class Zone(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='zones', null=True, blank=True)
```

And I need to contruct a filter along the lines of:

```
u = User.objects.filter(...zones contains a particular zone...)
```

It has to be a filter on User and it has to be a single filter parameter. The reason for this is that I am constructing a URL querystring to filter the admin user changelist: `http://myserver/admin/auth/user/?zones=3`

It seems like it should be simple but my brain isn't cooperating!

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you right - isn't `User.objects.filter(zones__id=<id>)` or `User.objects.filter(zones__in=<id(s)>)` good for this?

Comment: That's ok :) BTW `User.objects.filter(zones__in=<id(s)>)` should probably be `User.objects.filter(zones__id__in=<id(s)>)`

Comment: Just wanted to point out for anyone Googling this, that it only works if related_name is set. zone_set wouldn't work, for example. Wasted a good half-hour on that :-)

Comment: @user391538 That can't be true though. If you do not set related_name, related_query_name is the name of the model. You can read [django docs on related_query_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name)

Answer (score 246, accepted):

Just restating what Tomasz said.

There are many examples of `FOO__in=...` style filters in the [many-to-many](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/tests/many_to_many/tests.py) and [many-to-one](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/tests/many_to_one/tests.py) tests.  Here is  syntax for your specific problem:

```
users_in_1zone = User.objects.filter(zones__id=<id1>)
# same thing but using in
users_in_1zone = User.objects.filter(zones__in=[<id1>])

# filtering on a few zones, by id
users_in_zones = User.objects.filter(zones__in=[<id1>, <id2>, <id3>])
# and by zone object (object gets converted to pk under the covers)
users_in_zones = User.objects.filter(zones__in=[zone1, zone2, zone3])
```

The double underscore (__) syntax is used all over the place when working with [querysets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/).

Comment: double underscore  (argh. 3 hours lost to that one)

Comment: Can you please say, what to do if I want the users who are in a set of zones not just any one of them? Lets say find user who are in zone1, zone3, .. and zone 10

Comment: Look at the `...__in` examples after `# filtering on a few zones, by id`.  Those show filtering for multiple ids/objects ( in this case).  Just pass in the zone1, zone3, and zone10 ids/objects you care about.  Or add a 4th if needed.

Comment: Thx. I was only filtering against a single value, instead of an array containing the single value.

Comment: What if I want to filter by exact list of zones. like
`exact_zones = User.objects.filter(zones=[1,2])` I got error says it should be ID not a list. But I need these exact zones.

Comment: See `...__in` examples.  In your case `.filter(zones__in=[1, 2])`.

Answer (score 57):

Note that if the user may be in multiple zones used in the query, you may probably want to add `.distinct()`. Otherwise you get one user multiple times:

```
users_in_zones = User.objects.filter(zones__in=[zone1, zone2, zone3]).distinct()
```

Answer (score 11):

another way to do this is by going through the intermediate table.  I'd express this within the Django ORM like this:

```py
UserZone = User.zones.through

# for a single zone
users_in_zone = User.objects.filter(
  id__in=UserZone.objects.filter(zone=zone1).values('user'))

# for multiple zones
users_in_zones = User.objects.filter(
  id__in=UserZone.objects.filter(zone__in=[zone1, zone2, zone3]).values('user'))
```

it would be nice if it didn't need the `.values('user')` specified, but Django (version 3.0.7) seems to need it.

the above code will end up generating SQL that looks something like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT user_id FROM userzones WHERE zone_id IN (1,2,3))
```

which is nice because it doesn't have any intermediate joins that could cause duplicate users to be returned

Comment: Hiya. This isn't an answer in itself. You should add a comment or edit QB's answer rather than add an additional partial answer.

Comment: Yeah - if you want to edit your answer so it's complete in it's own right (unless you've got enough karma to edit QB's answer?) then that would be the best bet. Ideally on StackOverflow there's "one correct answer". It doesn't usually work out quite that neatly but it's worth aiming for.

Comment: @AndyBaker agreed!  in retrospect QB's answer should probably be a comment on istruble's answer, while I think mine is distinct enough to warrant separate answer, but ah well

Answer (score 2):

You can also lookup simply by name, without `__in`:

```py
class Publication(models.Model):
    ...

class Article(models.Model):
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)

Article.objects.filter(publications=1)
# or
Article.objects.filter(publications=p1)
```

Works with `related_name` as well from my tests.

per [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where some users ended with a free role and also a paid role, so I needed to select users that have two specific roles on the many to many field.

I did something like this, works like a charm

```
roles = [premium_role, default_role]

DiscordUser.objects.filter(guild=guild)
    .annotate(freemium=Count('roles', filter=Q(roles__in=roles)))
    .filter(freemium=2)
    .values('id')
```

If you want this to be more dynamic, you can change this line with

```
.filter(freemium=len(roles))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Q** object if you have more complex query in the scenario like this question.

based on this question suppose you want to filter Users with specific id(e.g. 10) and filter Zones with the name that starts with 'europe'

query would be like this:

```
filtered_zone = Q(zones__in=Zone.objects.filter(name__startswith='europe')
result = User.objects.filter(Q(id=10) & Q(filtered_zone))
```