# How to query a many to many relationship in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a list of organizations that full under different organization types. I have a table that holds the name, phone, etc... and then another table that has an id fixed to an organization type. Then a table that holds the many to many relationship because an organization can have many different organization types.

What I'm wanting to do is list all the clubs alphabetically that fall under every organizational type.

I'm not sure if this needs to be done in `views.py` or if it should be done in my template file.

Here are my models:

```
class ClubType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Club(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 250,
            verbose_name = "Club or Organization Name",
            )
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            auto_now_add = True,
            )
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(
            auto_now = True,
            auto_now_add = True,
            )
    club_type = models.ManyToManyField(ClubType)
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 100,
            blank = True, null = True
            )
    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length = 250,
            blank = True, null = True,
            )
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length = 250,
            blank = True, null = True,
            )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name', )
```

I'm a noob to python and Django so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you update the question with some code ? At least the models. Did you use ManyToManyField for the relation ?

Comment: I second that motion, some code would be good, it is hard to answer this question otherwise.

Comment: code from the models.py for those tables you have mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you need to do the following steps:

1. Get the distinct club types
2. For each club type, select the clubs that include that type (also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218327/django-manytomany-filter))
3. Sort the selection from #2 alphabetically

There are many ways to achieve this, and I would not recommend putting this logic into the template for the simple fact that expressing the logic behind it is probably easier in the view (or in a [custom Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods) if you get adventurous later in your Django life)

An example (**warning:** untested code):

```
# step 1
club_types = ClubTypes.objects.distinct()

# step 2 & #3
club_sets = []
for current_club_type in club_types:
    cset = Clubs.objects.filter(club_type__id=current_club_type.pk).order_by('name')
    club_sets.append((current_club_type, cset))
```

What you are left with in the end is a list of club type lists, each sorted by name that is of the form:

> [     (clubtype1, [ club1, club2, ...]),   (clubtype2, [ club2, club8, ...]), ... ]

Comment: what would the logic in my template file look like? Would I have to do a forloop there? This looks like it's creating one big array am I right?

Comment: Assuming you want to display the information as a list of clubtypes, each with a sublist of clubs, then you would just need a 2 nested for loops to walk over the ``club_sets`` result.  updated answer with an example of what the data in ``club_sets`` will look like.

Comment: This works mostly except I'd like to be able to display the club type name as well above each list of all club types

Comment: ok, it's simple to remember the clubtype as well.  the example has been updated. now you get a list of tuples of the form (clubtype, clubs).