# Django filter Many-to Many-field Inline

Tags: python, django, inline-formset

So I'm trying to filter the fields in an inlineform.  I followed [this SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218327/django-manytomany-filter) Course and Strand are filtering to the course correctly but concept does not filter and returns all records.

```
    if db_field.name == 'course':
        kwargs['queryset'] = Course.objects.filter(pk = course_id)
    elif db_field.name == 'strand':
        kwargs['queryset'] = Strand.objects.filter(course = course_id)
    elif db_field.name == 'concepts':
        kwargs['queryset'] = Concept.objects.filter(course__id = course_id)
```

the models I'm working with are:

```
class Indicator (models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) # AutoField?
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    indicator_text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    explained = models.TextField("Explained",blank=True)
    course = models.ForeignKey('curriculum.Course')
    theme = models.ForeignKey(Theme)        
    strand = models.ForeignKey(Strand,blank=True,null=True)
    level = models.ForeignKey(Level,blank=True,null=True)
    concepts = models.ManyToManyField(Concept,blank=True)

class Course (models.Model):
 id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) # AutoField?
 course_text = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
 slug = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
 excerpt = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
 description = models.TextField(blank=True)     
 zorder = models.IntegerField(default=0)
 license = models.TextField("License", blank=True, null=True)
 icon = models.ImageField("Icon",upload_to='icons/',blank=True,null=True)

class Theme (models.Model):
 id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) # AutoField?
 code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
 course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
 theme_text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 description = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=1000)
 zorder = models.IntegerField()

class Strand (models.Model):
 id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) # AutoField?
 code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
 course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
 strand_text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 description = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=1000)

class Concept (models.Model):
 id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) # AutoField?
 code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
 course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
 concept_text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 description = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=255)
```

Is this a known issue or a quirk of what I'm trying to do?

Thanks as always for your help.

Chris

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? what is the error message? traceback?

Comment: could you show the strand, concept and course models?

Comment: also fix the indenting of the if on the question, please, or add the if that those elif's relate to

Comment: question edited to address above comments