# django manytomanyfield filter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, manytomanyfield

so I am building an app with django django rest and I have some issues with many to many fields in my models,

in the app there are two models that are connected by a many to many field option and version. the problem is that I want to filter my option and get only the option related to a number of version and only those who have (Default True).
here is my models

```
class Option(models.Model):
    Code_Option = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    Nom_Option = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    option_Version = models.ManyToManyField(Version,through='Option_Version')

class Option_Version(models.Model):
    option = models.ForeignKey(Option, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    version = models.ForeignKey(Version, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Default = models.BooleanField(default = False)

class Version(models.Model):
    Code_Version = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    Nom_Version = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Id_Modele = models.ForeignKey(Modele, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Version_set')
```

and here is what I tried to do

```
class Option_defaut_Version(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = Option_Sereializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        id_version = self.kwargs['Id_Version'] 
//id version refers to Code_Version from Version (it's the PK) and I get it from the url ex: option/default/<srt:Id_Version>
        return Option.objects.filter(option_Version__version = id_version).filter(option_Version__default = "True")
```

and here is my sereilasers :

```
class Option_Sereializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Option
        fields = [
            'Code_Option',
            'Nom_Option',
            'option_Version'
        ]

class Option_Version_Sereializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Option_Version
        fields = [
            'option',
            'version',
            'Default'
        ]
class Version_Sereializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Version
        fields = [
            'Nom_Version',
            'Code_Version'
        ]
```

also I tried this:

```
class option_version_default(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = Option_Version_Sereializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Option_Version.objects.all()
```

the result was an error:

```
AttributeError at /option/default/v1

type object 'Option_Version' has no attribute 'objects'
```

if anyone could help me I would apreciate it

ps: I saw a lot of other questions and answers also the doc from django django rest but it didn't help me

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you explain your problem more precisely? What is the error?
I see that you use Case sensitive to describe your fields. So maybe there is the error: .filter(option_Version__Default=True)

Comment: well the error is :

FieldError at /option/default/v1
Related Field got invalid lookup: version

(option/default/v1 is the url for the class and the "v1" is the version pk)

Comment: my problem is that it kind of don't reconginse the other field (default) in the manytomanyfield.
I just want to filter my request by the two creteria version=v1 and default=true, but I didn't find something useful when it comes to custom manytomanyfield in other docs

Comment: also the problem is not "True" ===>  True

Comment: Please edit your question and add the Option_Version_Serializer and what is Id_Version? na id or an Object? Did you check this Answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218327/django-manytomany-filter

Comment: I edited my post with th sereializers, idèversion refers to Code_Version from Version.
and yes I already checked that answer it was useful for another manytomany field but not this one. this one has a through and for some reason it doesn't act like a normal one

Comment: >type object 'Option_Version' has no attribute 'objects'
Looks like an import issue. Did you import Option_Version?

Comment: or did you two methods/Models that are called Option_Version?

Comment: -yes, I imported everything needed.
- no, it was the only method called Option_Version.
thank you all for your help, I made it work by migrating everything to Version instead of Option (manytomany field in version Model , views and sereializers in the version.sereializer file).
I still don't know where is the problem in this, but at least it works.