# How am I able to filter post tags in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a blog type website where users can add tags to their posts and I want people to be able to filter by tag.
Here is my `models.py`

```py
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='posts',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    text = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag,related_name='tags',blank=True)
```

I cut a lot of the irrelevant model fields out so you weren't bombarded with lots of text.
Now here is my `views.py`

```py
class TagFilterView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'mainapp/tags_.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        object_list = Post.objects.filter(tags=tag).distinct()
        return object_list
```

Here is my url pattern

```py
path('tag/<int:pk>/',views.TagFilterView.as_view(),name='tag_view'),
```

And finally here is the HTML file

```html
{% extends 'mainapp/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Tags</h1>
    {% for post in object_list %}
        <h2>{{ post }}</h2>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I have tried lots of different filter combos and filter tags, but this seems to be the closest I think.
So basically I want to know how I can filter posts to the specific tags they have associated with them. So for example, if a post has a programming tag, and I go to `/tag/1` or something like that, it will filter so only the posts with the programming tag are shown.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: did you try this way

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218327/django-manytomany-filter

Comment: I have and so far none of the methods there have worked for my problem

Comment: what is `tag` here `(tags=tag)`? Is that a model instance or tag name?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're getting tag, but here's what I'd do.

```
class TagFilterView(ListView):
   ...

   def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(
            tags__id=self.kwargs['id']).distinct()
```

Comment: This gets a keyerror on ```id``` in my case

Comment: Does the code not mean that one is trying to filter for the tag id on the ```Tag``` model? Or am I missing something here

Comment: The original question has a different model, Post being used for the view. The view is returning posts filtered by tag.