# drf filter by multiple ManyToManyField ids

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here is my models

```
class Mediums(models.Model):
    medium_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Artwork(models.Model):
    title             = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    mediums           = models.ManyToManyField(Mediums, blank=True, related_name="artwork")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'artwork'
```

I am using django-reft-framework .

How can i fetch artwork by filtering multiple medium_id.
I  checked drf doc could not find option to filter ManyToManyField

Pse take a look

Comment: You can use `__in` with `mediums` so: `Artwork.objects.filter(mediums__in=Medium.objects.filter(<your_medium_filter>))`. You can find the doc and some examples [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: How can i add that in drf filterset_fields

Comment: if you want filtering at a url level, you can look into https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/ or https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ and please make it clear in the question

Answer (score 0):

documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#in

```
Artwork.objects.filter(mediums__in=medium_ids_or_objects)
```

similar question
[Django ManyToMany filter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218327/django-manytomany-filter)